# histogram and scatter plot on the same graph but the axis overlapped

Tags: r

I am plotting a histogram of actual data along with a density plot on the same graph but the x axis and y axis all mixed up. Is there a way to make sure the graph has the same axis e.g set a range to the graph for both the plot.

The reason that I put histogram and density plot together is for comparisons. The data range for both plots are similar but they alway produce two labels on the same axis making it unreadable.

```
a <- rnorm(100, 3, 7)
x <- c(0:200)
plot(0.5 * dpois(x, 4) + ((1 - 0.5) * dpois(x, 2)))
lines(0.5 * dpois(x, 4) + ((1 - 0.5) * dpois(x, 2)))
par(new = TRUE)
hist(a)
```

Comment: To put things on the same graph, they have to have the same x and y axes. You could do a panel plot with `mfrow`/`mfcol`, if you like.

Comment: You can have a dual axis. I wrote an answer on this before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since nobody answers my question. I have figured it out.

set the same `xlim` and `ylim` to **both** graph which makes aligned the x,y axes.